# How to run test in nightwatch?

Tags: npm, nightwatch.js

I just installed git clone https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch.git and when I run :

```
npm run unit-tests
```

from the commandline in windows I get an error:

```
> ./bin/nightwatch -c test/nightwatch.json

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Got a sneaky feeling it will work in OSX but can I run this in windows in the commandline?

Comment: You should have a quick look here once: https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/wiki/Windows-Quick-Start

Comment: you ran npm install first, I presume? (just checking)

Comment: yes I ran npm install and can confirm it works on latest osx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it had to put "node" in front of it.